# How to enable Dropbox panel icon at startup in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, icons, dropbox, lxpanel

I installed Dropbox in Lubuntu. It works perfectly, but panel icon is not shown, because Nautilus is not default file-manager in Lubuntu.

I've been searching for several forum pages at Askubuntu, Ubuntuforums and [ArchLinux](http://bbs.archlinux.org) Forums. They doesn't work entirely in Lubuntu. 
The best I got is this icon, that is shown in this image,

[image]

but it doesn't work at all.

So I ask: **Is there any solution for Dropbox Panel Icon in Lubuntu?**

Answer (score 6):

I worked on a solution for this. If I run these commands:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
dropbox stop
sleep 5
dbus-launch dropbox start -i
```

Dropbox icon will work like a charm, as image below:

[image]

So I saved a bash script as `/opt/dropbox-start.sh`

Boring is having to open a terminal to execute it. If I put in `~/.profile`, it locks lxsession startup. Changing the Exec line in `~/.config/autostart/dropbox` launcher, doesn't work, because this launcher is a copy from `/usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop` and it will be replaced by this one at system startup.

So I decided to change Exec line directly in `/usr/share/applications/dropbox.desktop`launcher, as it follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Dropbox
GenericName=File Synchronizer
Comment=Sync your files across computers and to the web
Exec=bash /opt/dropbox-start.sh
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=dropbox
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;
StartupNotify=false
```

This solution works even if there are several accounts in the computer, because the change was not saved in `$HOME` folder. To assure dropbox will autostart, check at

> Preferences > Default Applications for LXSession

if Dropbox is checked as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Great! It works! I repeated these commands in other computer, worked like a charm...